# DB2 Get value based on 5 character of field

Tags: sql, db2

I am working with a pretty badly designed table. I have a field called optional fields which for some reason has been used as a catch-all for someone who didn't want to create the table correctly.

I need to make a query where I look at this optional_fields value and do a comparison on the fifth value of the string in optional_fields.

The value from this field is something like `NN14YN...N`

My query would be something like:

```
SELECT COMPANY_NUMBER
FROM table
WHERE fifth character of OPtional Fields = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the supported [string functions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011043.html?lang=en-us&cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0#r0011043__t11043-7) in DB2 (according to the documentation for *DB2 for Linux UNIX and Windows 9.7.0*) it would seem that `substr` could be used:

```
SELECT COMPANY_NUMBER
FROM table
WHERE substr(optional_Fields,5,1) = 'Y'
```

Comment: thank you very much, that was the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the great answer from @jpw, if you for some reason need to check multiple positions within the string (which I have unfortunately had to do at one time), you can use an `IN`, and invert the "normal" order, like so:

```
...
WHERE 'Y' in (
     substr(t.flags_field, 123, 1)
    ,substr(t.flags_field, 19, 1)
    ,substr(t.flags_field, 128, 1)
    ,substr(t.flags_field, 1, 1) 
)
```

Just thought I would share. It surprised me the first time I used it!

Comment: Thank you for that addendum, that will come in very handy.